# Subclass method overloading to super class

Tags: overloading

I need help understanding overloading/overriding and the specifics. I get the general idea yet I'm still not understanding details.

Can a method in a subclass overload a method in the super class?

Comment: Please specify the language you're talking about.

Comment: Java - sorry I should have said that

Answer (score 0):

If two methods (one method is defined in base class and second method is defined in derived class ) have same name,same arguments,same return type but the body of two methods is different then we say that overriding is taking place . But if two methods have same name,same return type and different arguments then we will say that overloading is taking place .

```
void run(int a,int b)    //base class method
void run(int a)          //derived class method
```

This is an example of overloading .